# OpenGL textures taking up too much memory

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have 75 * 9 * 32 images, with a total of 64 MB on harddrive in PNG format. If I load the images, which are 128*256 pixels each, it takes up a whopping 1.5 GB of memory in RAM! I have no mipmapping enabled.

*I am figuring this could be because the GPU only stores raw images, is there a way to tighten the memory usage?*

I am loading the textures with the use of a framebuffer object, which is created only once.

I use the following for loading the textures:

```
        QImage catchImage = catchFbo->toImage();
        QImage t = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(catchImage);

        glGenTextures( 1, &Item::texture[i] );
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, Item::texture[i] );
        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, t.width(), t.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t.bits() );
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
```

EDIT: GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA instead of GL_RGBA seems to make a large difference. It now uses 500 MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am figuring this could be because the GPU only stores raw images,

Well, of course they are in raw format. Although it would be neat for GPUs to directly support Deflate and JPEG decompression, they don't support it.

> is there a way to tighten the memory usage?

You could use a compressed texture format. Yes, modern GPUs *do* support on-the-fly decompression, but the codecs used are very different from PNG or JPEG.

> I am loading the textures with the use of a framebuffer object, which is created only once.

Why? FBOs are meant for other things. You can load a QImage from a file directly without such a proxy.

Comment: Your post is somewhat contradictive. *Well, of course they are in raw format* and *You could use a compressed texture format.*. Anyway, the FBO is building the images (and then loaded from FBO), not loading them from harddisk.

Comment: @RobotRock: Sorry for that confusion. If you don't request a compressed format explicitly, the GPU will keep the textures in uncompressed, raw format. BTW: If you're building your image by FBO, then the way over a QImage goes two times through the bottleneck of transferring things to and from CPU memory to GPU. Just use glCopyTexImage or glCopyTexSubImage to transfer FBO contents into a texture. Or render directly to texture (by binding it as color attachment) and save the copy process alltogether.

Comment: You are right about the roundtripping but I can not get copyTexImage to work across glWidgets.

Comment: @RobotRock: Share the contexts of the QGLWidgets! By sharing the contexts all textures are available to all contexts in the share group.

Comment: Does this also apply to framebuffers? Because I seem to have read that it is not possible with FBOs.

Comment: @RobotRock: FBOs are basically state trackers, similar to Vertex Array Objects. You can neither share VAOs nor FBOs. But you can share textures just fine. So if you attach a texture as color attachment to an FBO, you can use it from another context as sampler source just fine (it only needs to be unbound from the FBO, or the FBO itself unbound in the other context).

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement clipping.  Of course that in of itself isn't going to prevent occupation of memory, so you need to lazy-load images if and when an image falls in your view scope.  A decent article about this is [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Clipping).

Comment: Sorry, but in which way does clipping help the OP with his memory consumption? Clipping is a per primitive operation, to cut (=clip) a primitive to viewport dimensions. I think you meant culling, but that won't help the OP either. Also lazy-loading images can be tricky as well.

Comment: No I meant clipping.  Clipping can be expanded to not only show what should be visible but load only what should be visible as well, though that requires that you do a little bit extra work.  Perhaps it's not an easier solution, but if tomorrow it's 3 GB rather than 1.5, he's going to have the same problem all over again with compression.  This is a better long-term solution.  I don't think it was appropriate to rate me down...

Comment: -1: @Neil: That's nonsense. Clipping does *nothing* about how much memory gets used. If you "expand" it to "load only what should be visible", it's not *clipping* anymore. Clipping is a hardware function of the GPU. You can't "expand" it to anything.

Comment: @Nicol_Bolas, That's why I said "Of course that in of itself isn't going to prevent occupation of memory,.."  Did you even read what I posted?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert them to a more compressed format or lazy-load them from the disk, but that's about it.